# Wordpress Limit Word of a post disables formatting

Tags: php, html, wordpress, posts

I've put a limit on my post length by creating a custom wordpress plugin. But this creates a new issue where the layout of my blog posts is destroyed.

Lay-Out Without The Plugin Activated:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjUAr.jpg

Lay-Out With The Plugin Activated:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJJHa.jpg

```
function limit_words_on_posts($content)
{
// Get the post content
$post_type = get_post_type();
if ($post_type == 'post'){
$post = get_post();
$url = 'https://www.vierenzestig.nl/';
$postslug = $post->post_name;

// Limit the post content
$text = $content;
$words = 300; 
$link = $url . $postslug;
$more = '...<br/><br/><strong>Wilt u dit artikel verder lezen? <a style="color: red; text- 
decoration: underline;" href="'.$link.'">Ga dan naar VierenZestig.NL!</a></strong>';


$excerpt = wp_trim_words( $text, $words, $more );

return $excerpt;
} else {
return $content;
}

}
```

As you can see the line breaks etc are removed while using the plugin. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `wp_trim_words` strip all tags from the content it has.

**You can use this code:**

```
$excerpt = force_balance_tags(html_entity_decode(wp_trim_words(htmlentities($text), $words, $more)));
```

Comment: Thanks! Was looking for days for this!

Comment: Glad I can help.